# How to avoid margins between children and parent div?

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div that has multiple children. I want the children to have spacing between eachother, so I give them margins. This margin obviously (but undesirably) introduces space between the parent and the children as well. What is the cleanest way to get rid of the space between the children and parent?

If I did not have to worry about sizing, or a dynamic number of children, I could individually set selective margins to 0 to achieve the result, but this is hacky.

It seems like this ought to be a common task, so I'm hoping there's a simple css attribute that I'm unaware of.

Here is an example of the situation I described above.

```css
.parent {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background:blue;
  margin:0 12px 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can clarify what your desired output is? (maybe add an image?)

Comment: here's the output I want, as well as the solution (thanks to @calvintwr's answer below) : https://jsfiddle.net/s2uakraz/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap the child in a container and assign `margin:-10px` to expand the wrapper so as to offset the border.

I would also add `overflow: hidden` on .parent so that the wrapper doesn't actually become bigger than its parent to avoid DOM complications.

```css
    .parent {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        font-size: 0;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: -10px;
    }
    .child {
        display: inline-block;
        background:blue;
        flex-grow: 0;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        margin:10px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Then this is also not the solution what OP wants :P

Comment: @TusharGupta, Why isn't this the solution I want? After changing the parent's width and height to 100%, you can resize the control and get exactly the behavior I was asking for. This looks like the answer. I'm just verifying a bit and will mark it as such soon.

Comment: @vivekmaharajh Then you should look that this has margin at the bottom and to the lright which u dont want and you mentioned on my answer as ur first comment,,.....either u r not clear or u r making it complex!!

Comment: @TusharGupta, even though there's a margin, due to his offset of -10, it does not appear to have any margin at all.

Comment: @TusharGupta i don't think you understand the box model. Here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: @vivekmaharajh i improved the answer. you might want to add `overflow: hidden`. I think that's good practice. Inner DOMs shouldn't be bigger than its parent unless it is intended for.

Comment: I'd like to note that I've since discovered "calc" in css, which also presents an elegant solution to this question as well, since it allows you to mix % and px and have the browser perform the calculations at 'runtime'.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the margin as `top right bottom left` , use it as per your need , the example is given below

```css
.parent {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background:blue;
  margin:0 10px 0 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
    <div class = "child"></div>
 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because 1) if the parent is resized so that the children wrap to 2 rows, then there'd be no vertical spacing between them, and 2) you've still got margin space between the right edge of the parent and the children

Comment: @vivekmaharajh Then use it wisely ....u can give the bottom margin too but that would be your discretion...I have given the way ...You can use padding if you need and change the values to percentage for responsiveness..

Comment: I don't see how i'd be able to use this wisely to solve my requirements of 1) having internal spacing between the elements, and 2) having no spacing between parent and children